# Multiple output pdfs with limited info in one

Tags: xetex, privacy

I am making my resume using and for xelatex.  Certain versions of my resume have my name and address, they others, those which are public do not.  Is there an easy way to hide this information on the public versions.  As of now I just run

```
xelatex file.tex
```

I really don't want to have to go in and edit the file every time. any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your document using a template like the following (call this `file.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifinclude
\ifdefined\public\else\includetrue\fi
\begin{document}
Here is some content that is always visible.

\ifinclude
Here is some content that depends on a condition.
\fi

Here is some content that is always visible.
\end{document}
```

This defines a conditional `\ifinclude` that can either be true (`\includetrue`) or false (`\includefalse`, default). This condition is switched on/off by virtue of whether a macro `\public` is defined or not (using the e-TeX primitive `\ifdefined`). Wrapping the non-public details within your document/resume around a primitive `\ifinclude`...`\fi` conditional, you can selectively include this content or not, based on the existence of `\public`, which you then define at the command line. For example,

```
xelatex \def\public{}\input{file.tex}
```

produces

[image]

while

```
xelatex file.tex
```

produces

[image]

since `\public` is undefined.